# Remote Sql Performance Issue Code Time and Sql Profile times are not matching up

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I have a local application (Web Application but reproducible in console app) that is accessing a remote SQL server hosted on AWS. We are having a performance issue that I am trying to debug but am having difficulty.
I ran the Visual Studio 2013 performance tool and all indications that I have a bad query (cmd.ExecuteReader is 99% of the sample data and about 9 seconds of time).
Next logical thing to do is to run a Query profiler on the sql server hosted at AWS. This is where it gets weird, the query profiler reports the query takes 20ms.

So I cannot resolve the difference in time here, in my code it is taking 9 seconds to execute a query but sql profiler reports the same query is take 20ms. Is there something else I can look at from the sql side (maybe connection time, waiting time, sending time)?

Comment: Are you running straight SQL query, or executing a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

The part you are missing is the network traffic. Query execution time on the server is how long it takes to execute the query... with little or no network traffic involved.

Once you execute it remotely the query takes the same amount of time but now the result set has to get from the remote DB to your client. Depending on the size of each row, how many rows and the network latency this can take add quite a bit of time.

How big is your result set?